# What is the difference between e.err and e.errstr?

Tags: ruby, database, error-handling, dbi

I'm trying to create a database connection using Ruby and have come across some advice that I should put in error notices if I ever come across errors in the future.

Here is a sample code that contains #{e.err} and #{e.errstr}.

What do e.err and e.errstr mean and how are they beneficial when handling with databases?

```
    require "dbi"

    begin
        # connect to the MySQL server
        dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:TESTDB:localhost", "username", "password")
        # get server version string and display it
        row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
        puts "Server version: " + row[0]
    rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
        puts "An error occurred"
        puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
        puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
    ensure
        # disconnect from server
        dbh.disconnect if dbh
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are provided by the ruby's Database Independent Interface,

```
e.err -> will give you the error code like 4xx
e.errstr -> will give you the error message like 'unable to find the specified database'
```

Hope this makes it clear